# GitHub API with Angular - how to get user's public repos?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, github, github-api

I'm trying to print out the repos count of each angular organisation member on GitHub. I already succeeded to print all of the usernames, but I can't print the repos and don't know what causes it.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>GitHub App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="cntrlr.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myctrl">
  <h1>GitHub users ranking</h1>
  <h3>{{org.login}}</h3>
  {{user.public_repos}}
<p ng-repeat="user in memberall">{{user.login}}, {{user.public_repos}}</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the JS:

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.github.com/orgs/angular'+ '?access_token=xxx' })
            .then(function(response) {
            $scope.org = response.data;
        }, function(error) {
            displayError("Something went wrong");
        });

    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.github.com/orgs/angular/members'+ '?access_token=xxx' })
            .then(function(response) {
            $scope.members = response.data;
        }, function(error) {
            displayError("Something went wrong");
        });

    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.github.com/orgs/angular/members?page=2'+ '&access_token=xxx' })
            .then(function(response) {
            $scope.members2 = response.data;
        }, function(error) {
            displayError("Something went wrong");
        });

    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.github.com/orgs/angular/members?page=3'+'&access_token=xxx' })
            .then(function(response) {
            $scope.members3 = response.data;
        }, function(error) {
            displayError("Something went wrong");
        });

     $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.github.com/users' + '?access_token=xxx' })
            .then(function(response) {  
            $scope.user = response.data;
            $scope.memberall = $scope.members.concat($scope.members2, $scope.members3);
                for(var index = 0; index < $scope.memberall.length; index++) {
                   $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + $scope.memberall[index].login + '?access_token=xxx');
                   $scope.repos = response.data[index].public_repos;
                }
            }, function(error) {
            displayError("Something went wrong");
});
    }]);
```

I would really appreciate if someone would tell me what mistake did I make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just call $http but don't handle the returned data.

```
$http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + $scope.memberall[index].login).then(function(res) {
    console.log(res.data.public_repos);
});
```

This gets you the repos ids.

You can get the actual repos at this url (replace the 'xxx' with your token):

```
'https://api.github.com/users/' + $scope.memberall[index].login + '/repos'
```

EDIT: The key here is to use array.forEach() so that you don't have to play with array indexes (which will not work with a simple for loop since $http "creates" a new scope and the variable i is not accessible inside)

```js
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.github.com/orgs/angular'+ '?access_token=xxx' })
            .then(function(response) {
            $scope.org = response.data;
        }, function(error) {
            displayError("Something went wrong");
        });

    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.github.com/orgs/angular/members'+ '?access_token=xxx' })
            .then(function(response) {
            $scope.members = response.data;
        }, function(error) {
            displayError("Something went wrong");
        });

    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.github.com/orgs/angular/members?page=2'+ '&access_token=xxx' })
            .then(function(response) {
            $scope.members2 = response.data;
        }, function(error) {
            displayError("Something went wrong");
        });

    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.github.com/orgs/angular/members?page=3'+'&access_token=xxx' })
            .then(function(response) {
            $scope.members3 = response.data;
        }, function(error) {
            displayError("Something went wrong");
        });

     $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.github.com/users' + '?access_token=xxx' })
            .then(function(response) {  
            $scope.user = response.data;
            $scope.memberall = $scope.members.concat($scope.members2, $scope.members3);
                $scope.memberall.forEach(function(value, index) {
                   $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + value.login + '?access_token=xxx').then(function(res) {
                     //console.log(res.data.public_repos);
                     value.nbrRepos = res.data.public_repos;
                   });
                })
            }, function(error) {
            displayError("Something went wrong");
});
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myctrl">
<h1>GitHub users ranking</h1>
  <h3>{{org.login}}</h3>
  {{user.public_repos}}
<p ng-repeat="user in memberall">{{user.login}}, {{user.nbrRepos}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your code prints the repos count in the console, but it still does nothing in the HTML and I want to show the repos count next to the logins.

Comment: @Dorota I edited the snippet so that it shows the number of repos per user

Comment: Sir, you just made my day. Thank you very much.

Comment: Also, do you happen to have an idea how to get to the number of contribution each member did to the organisation? I cannot find the right way.

Comment: @Dorota take a look at this: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#get-contributors-list-with-additions-deletions-and-commit-counts (and browse the API for more resource)